# How to position a ScrolledWindow (tkinter) scrollbar at the bottom

Tags: python, tkinter, scrolledwindow

I am creating a gui with tkinter in python. I have created a scrollbar and this is what the section of code looks like:

```
beta_frame = Frame(width="500", height="680")
beta_frame.pack()
holder = ScrolledWindow(beta_frame, width=500, height=680)
holder.pack()
alpha_frame = holder.window
```

I would like to position this scrollbar at the very bottom every time something new is put on the screen (which would obviously be added to the bottom The only things I'm adding to the screen are labels and buttons), though I'm unsure how to do this and I've searched everywhere. All I came up with is the method see, which I am unsure if it is even applicable in this instance. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.see()` is the normal way to get Tkinter to auto-scroll to a given position, but that method only exists on the widgets that have built-in support for scrolling - Listbox, Canvas, Text, and Entry.  The Tix ScrolledWindow makes an ordinary Frame scrollable, so no such method will exist.

It appears that this line of code will do what you want:

```
holder.tk.eval(holder.vsb['command'] + " moveto 1.0")
```

`vsb` is the vertical scrollbar component of the ScrolledWindow, `'command'` is the scrollbar configuration option that specifies a callback to invoke when the position is changed.  This will refer to something deep inside Tix, but we don't care exactly what it is; we just invoke it with the same parameters that the scrollbar itself would, if being moved to the very end.

Comment: Where would I put this line of code? Right after I pack the holder frame, each time I put something new onto the screen (in the functions that create the buttons/text) or somewhere else? I've tried it a couple of places but have so far been unsuccessful

Comment: Each time you want to scroll to the bottom.  You may need to call `.update()` or `.update_idletasks()` first, to give `holder.window` a chance to resize to its new contents.

Comment: Thanks @jasonharper, I deleted my mistaken answer. Yours is great ;)